# C# WPF MVVW sampleapp w/ dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to learn WPF w/ MVVW since that seems the next step from windows forms
doing a small sample app but I'm stuck in a point where when changing a combobox w/ table names from a dataset - it's not changing the datagrid even if the datatable in the view model is already changed

plus the XAML returns an error from the view model

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agu7X-TLaSCt7DQ0il8CVcYlX39s

I guess the next step would be to do add/delete/update and write back to the database; my data is quite dynamically so therefore I don't want to create classes for every possible attribute and table as next time that I query a new attribute might have being added...

in my XAML I've this:

```
<localViews:GridView   Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="TableData"  DataContext="{Binding _DataTable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Tag="System.Data.DataTable" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

and in the viewModel:

```
    void cboBox_CurrentChanged(string curItem)
    {
        _DataTable = ds.Tables[curItem]; RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedCboItem");
    }
```

so when clicking in the combobox below - it doesn't change the grid contents to reflect new selected datatable that exists in the dataset

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebXsf.jpg

Comment: Is this the right property name (SelectedCboItem) in your view model ?

Answer (score 0):

this solves the problem in a non MVVW fashion

```
private void cboTables_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TableData == null | (TableData != null && TableData.DataContext == null)) { return; }
        TableData.xDataGrid.ItemsSource = (((DataTable)(TableData.DataContext)).DataSet.Tables[(string)cboTables.SelectedItem]).DefaultView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

_DataTable should be an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx).  This will then notify the bound object that something has changed.

However, if you want to update this based on the selected item in the combo box changing, I would suggest that you also bind the data source of the combo box (along with the selected item).